# Jolt transform - how to concat two properties

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have below input in `JSON`

```
{
 "firstName": "Scott",
 "lastName": "Parker"
}
```

I need in output follow structure

```
{
  data: {
    "fullName: "Scott Parker"
  }
}
```

I really don't understand how should work jolt transform processor in nifi

> Maybe there are any alternatives in nifi ?

Thanx a lot!!

Comment: Have you gone through this https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-stringFunctions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in Jagadesh's link is a good one, the `=concat` function does exactly what you want (even the field names are the same). Then you just need a shift spec to move the `fullName` field into the `data` field and ignore the rest:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      // String join the values in the array x, with a comma and a space
      "fullName": "=concat(@(1,firstName),' ',@(1,lastName))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fullName": "data.fullName"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: tanx a lot @mattyb