# Jolt transform - how to rename field with field value?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm wondering if there is any way to rename the field by concatenating the values of JSON attributes into existing attribute names using JOLT transformation.

Suppose we have **input** here:

```json
{
  "auth_id": "0000-0000-0000",
  "read_time": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.0",
  "src_name": "REQ-A001",
  "reading_a": "150.18",
  "reading_b": "12.10",
  "reading_c": "3.00",
  "note": 1
}
```

What I expect is to concatenate field values from `auth_id` and `read_time` before all existing field name, with a colon (`:`) as separator and the result would become:

**Expected:**

```json
{
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:auth_id": "0000-0000-0000-0000-0000",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:read_time": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.0",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:src_name": "REQ-A001",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:reading_a": "150.18",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:reading_b": "12.10",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:reading_c": "3.00",
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0:note": 1
}
```

So far I've referred to

- [Khusan Sharipov's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555157) for concatenating field value
- [DSC's digest of JOLT documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822607) to clarify how the operators do their job

and come up with a **JOLT spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      // concatenate field value auth_id and read_time, while using ":" as separator
      "ukey": "=concat(@(1,auth_id),':',@(1,read_time))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // concatenate field values before field name
        "@": "@(2,ukey):&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I got this output:

```json
{
  "0000-0000-0000:2022-01-10T00:00:00.0": {
    ":auth_id": "0000-0000-0000",
    ":read_time": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.0",
    ":src_name": "REQ-A001",
    ":reading_a": "150.18",
    ":reading_b": "12.10",
    ":reading_c": "3.00",
    ":note": 1
  }
}
```

I expect to use the JOLT spec in the **JoltTransformJSON** processor in **Nifi**.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you! This community has saved my sanity crisis on the job for over five years, 
and though I haven't answered a question yet, I think I could give out a neat, readable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shorter** spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@(1,auth_id).@(1,read_time).&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2:&1:&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Or you can use **another way** like below:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(2,auth_id)": "keys[#2]",
        "@(2,read_time)": "keys[#2]",
        "$": "keys[#2]",
        "@": "values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "keys": {
        "*": "=join(':',@0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        "*": "@(2,keys[#1])"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**1, Shift operation** Create `keys` and `values` separately.

**2, Modify operation** Concate all `keys` with `:`.

**3, Shift operation** Create our desired output.

**Note:** Please run each spec separately to understand this code better.

Comment: I didn't know using the wildcards in these specs would be this neat!
I've read both specs about how the data transform from one operation to another, and wow, such a super move.
Though both of you have a great answer, still, I'm accepting this one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ukey": "=concat(@(1,auth_id),':',@(1,read_time),':')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)" // reverse key-value pairs
      },
      "ukey": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=concat(@(1,ukey),@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "ukey": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)" // reverse key-value pairs back
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*note": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo1** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

the alternative option, which gives the same result , uses consecutive **shift** transformation specs after having used the **modify** transformation you already have, as follows

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ukey": "=concat(@(1,auth_id),':',@(1,read_time))"
    }
  },
  { // nest the attributes under common object with "ukey" key
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "@(2,ukey).&"
      }
    }
  },
  {// concatenate upper object and one level inner object keys for the attributes except for "ukey"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2:&1" // concatenation 
        },
        "ukey": {      // exception case
          "*": {
            "*": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo2** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Though in the first spec, I found that it will **merge field names into an array** on the first key-value reverse if they share the same value (such as `0`, `null` etc.), which I wasn't expecting,
the second spec is highly readable and looks nice to people who weren't familiar with the wildcards. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @LindenHSU have a nice study and work! Yes, I've thought on case to make it better after the first one. Best wishes.